# AWS CDK can't find ARN of dead letter queue when creating SQS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create an SQS with a dead letter queue but when I deploy AWS says it can't find the ARN for the dead letter queue.

My code is below for my SQS stack.

```py
class SqsCdkStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, app_name: str, **kwargs) -> None:

        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        dead_letter_queue: sqs.Queue = sqs.Queue(
            self,
            id="VfAwsRtsMlinfCdkDeadLetterQueue",
            queue_name=f"{app_name}-dead-letter-queue",
            retention_period=Duration.days(14)
        )

        self.sqs_queue: sqs.Queue = sqs.Queue(
            self,
            id="VfAwsRtsMlinfCdkContactResponseQueue",
            queue_name=f"{app_name}-contact-and-response-queue",
            retention_period=Duration.days(4),
            visibility_timeout=Duration.seconds(30),
            delivery_delay=Duration.seconds(0),
            receive_message_wait_time=Duration.seconds(0),
            max_message_size_bytes=262144,  # 256 KiB
            encryption=sqs.QueueEncryption.SQS_MANAGED,
            dead_letter_queue=sqs.DeadLetterQueue(
                max_receive_count=1,
                queue=dead_letter_queue
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation should know to create the DLQ before the Queue, but try making the dependency explicit with:

```py
self.sqs_queue.node.add_dependency(dead_letter_queue)
```